# Route DNS Requests between 2 different networks

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, domain-name-system, isa-server

I have a machine that bridges 2 networks with 2 network cards.

One network card is on the 255.255.255.0 subnet which has DNS servers available to it.

The second network card is on a private network 255.255.248.0 which does not have a DNS server on it.

I am using a Windows Server 2003 machine with ISA Server 2006 installed to control access. I have successfully got web traffic going through but I need to put an entry in the private network machines' hosts file to get it to resolve.

Is there a way either using a windows feature or ISA server I can route DNS requests through my gateway to a DNS server on the other subnet?

Comment: What is the default route on the clients that are making the DNS requests?

Comment: And do the clients already have the ip address of the DNS server?

Comment: default gateway on the clients is to the ISA Server that bridges the networks. I've configured the clients to have the IP Addresses of DNS servers on the network they can't see, not sure where to go from this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your ISA server is routing between the subnets, the easiest method is to give the upstream DNS server address(es) to the smaller subnet (either via DHCP or statically), set the ISA as the default gateway for the clients, and let them just query the upstream server directly.

Another alternative is to setup the MS DNS server on the ISA server and have it recurse to the upstream servers (i.e. run a caching DNS server on the ISA box).